# Database Tuning Advisor error: ...% of consumed workload has syntax errors

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-tuning-advisor, performance-tuning

Hi I've generated a trace file using SQL Server Profiler and save that trace as a table in SQL server DB. The trace file workload was generated by executing a query directly from SQL Serve Management Studio. So there were no syntax errors in the query.

Now I'm using SQL Server Database Tuning Advisor to see analysis recommendations. To achieve it specified the table name as a workload source and selected all interested databases. when database Tuning Advisor completes the analysis the "Process" tab appears and displays the following message for the "Consuming Workload" in the "Action" column.

### TITLE: DTAEngine

**"50% of consumed workload has syntax errors. Check tuning log for more information."**

I'm noticing three issues described below:

1) Before starting analysis I selected the "Save Session Log" checkbox. But the Tuning Log on the Process tab is empty;

2) I have only two types of reports generated after the analysis completes: the "Index Detail Report (current)" and the "Index Detail Report (recommended);

3) No Recommendation were generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the issues above was that I selected the "Showplan Statistics Profile" option under the "Performance" category on the Event Selection tab in SQL Server Profiler. Once I unchecked it and generated a new trace file workload, all the issues listed above had been resolved.

[image]